# Create and set styles in Excel cells using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, export-to-excel

How to create and set styles in Excel cells using C#?

I want to write something like "**April 1st**" with **st** as a **superscript**. 
I would be using a string format not a date format.

I have tried http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1hh9fza.aspx but getting an **The name 'Globals' does not exist in the current context** error. I have added assembly Microsoft.Office.Interlop.Excel. Am I missing any other assembly?

```
Excel.Style style = Globals.ThisWorkbook.Styles.Add("NewStyle");
```

Comment: What do you exactly mean by saying that IntelliSense doesn't let you to do this? Are there any errors? If yes, please include them in your question.

Comment: @KonradGadzina The name does not exist in the current context.

Comment: Is this a VSTO project?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhczd18c.aspx

Comment: @RichardMorgan No, its not a VSTO project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually don't want to change the font of the whole cell but you to change a portion of the text in the cell I take it.
You'll still need to retrieve the cell range and then adjust the characters within that range. here is an example where it's just adjusting the first cell. A1.

If you wanted to change the whole cell range to be superscript it would be done like this
    currentRange.Font.Superscript  = true;

```
void Main()
{
         var app = new Application();
        app.Visible = true;
        var workbook = app.Workbooks.Add(1);

        Sheets excelSheets = workbook.Worksheets;
        string currentSheet = "Sheet1";
        Worksheet worksheet1 = (Worksheet)excelSheets.get_Item(currentSheet);

        worksheet1.Cells[1, 1] = "April 1st";
        worksheet1.Cells[1, 2] = "April 2nd";
        worksheet1.Cells[1, 3] = "April 3rd";
        worksheet1.Cells[1, 4] = "April 4th";

        // fill in the starting and ending range programmatically this is just an example. 
        string startRange = "A1";
        string endRange = "A1";
        Range currentRange = worksheet1.get_Range(startRange , endRange );

        var text = currentRange.Text.ToString();
        int length = text.Length;
        int index = 0;
        if(text.Contains("st"))
        {
            index =text.IndexOf("st");
        }
        //The other checks for "nd", "rd", "th" obviously check to see a # precedes these.

        if(index > 0)
        {           
            currentRange.get_Characters( index+1, 2).Font.Superscript  = true;              
        }           
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As the MSDN article you've linked to states:

> Applies to: The information in this topic applies to document-level
>   projects and application-level projects for Office 2013 and Office
>   2010. See Features Available by Office Application and Project Type.

To use `Globals` class you have to create Office project. For another reference you can check [this question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/13236b1e-0eab-4ee5-8bc9-a53d8953ab5b/problems-creating-an-excel-addin-with-vsto?forum=vsto) about creating Office add-in:

> Globals.ThisAddin.Application can be only used in VSTO Add-In

Comment: Will I have to add a new Office application or VSTO project for using superscripts and subscripts in excel of the type I have explained in the example in question?

Comment: @user2951819 I see some examples with superscript without using `Globals`, but with some external libraries - http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/cellsnet/Apply+Superscript++and++Subscript+Effects+on+Fonts I can't check if it works with basic Office Interop at the moment.

Comment: I can't use them. I will need some libraries or mabe another application type.